# Is there a way to override the Vorpal mode exit command?

Tags: javascript, vorpal.js

I'm using Vorpal `mode` to allow users to type in text, that I later parse (I couldn't find a way to do it with a regular `command` since I can't account for all text in advance). When the user types `exit` he's taken out of the mode. I'd like that to be a different string - or perhaps an additional string (say `quit` or `end`).

Is there a way I can either override the `exit` command, or failing that, trigger it myself when a certain string is provided by the user?

Sample code:
Here's an [exercise that implements a Reverse Polish Notation](https://github.com/TravelingTechGuy/RPN/blob/master/index.js) calculator. If you look at the `handleInput` function (line 47), you'll see that I had to manually handle the `q` string and kill the process - where all I want it to do is behave like the mode's `exit` command (somewhere around line 74).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to currently do this, however you can [file an issue on Github](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/issues) to add it as an enhancement, as this is a good idea.

However, [it looks like the `catch` command](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/API-%7C-vorpal.catch) might be more what you're looking for. This accepts any arbitrary command, without being in a "mode".

---

#### Update

In looking at your code, it looks like `catch` would do the trick. Something like this:

```
vorpal
  .catch('[input...]')
  .action(function (args, cb) {
    handleInput(args.input.join(' '), cb);
  });
```

In the above example, it will be as if you are already in a "mode" as soon as the application starts. Any command that doesn't match a pre-defined command (such as `exit`) will call the catch method instead, and it can behave like a mode by accepting variadic arguments and joining them.

Does that make sense?

Comment: `catch` does have potential. But it does not help once you're in a `mode` - it is described as just another command.

Comment: True. Could you update your question with an example of what you're trying to accomplish? That would give me a better idea.

Comment: Actually, I can do better. I'l add a link to the repo. Cheers!